# Problems running distributed xgboost with YARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, xgboost

I am esperiencing some problem with the tutorial about xgboost distributed mode on YARN.

I followed their instruction but there is some problem that I was not able to solve.

I am running 2 EC2 instances with Hadoop 2.6.0 (which seems properly configured).

When I run their demo with the following command:

```
cd xgboost/demo/distributed-training
# Use dmlc-submit to submit the job.
../../dmlc-core/tracker/dmlc-submit --cluster=yarn --num-workers=2 --worker-cores=2\
../../xgboost mushroom.aws.conf nthread=2\
data=s3://${BUCKET}/xgb-demo/train\
eval[test]=s3://${BUCKET}/xgb-demo/test\
model_dir=s3://${BUCKET}/xgb-demo/model
```

I get the following error from the Hadoop container:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./launcher.py", line 82, in <module>
 main()
 File "./launcher.py", line 77, in main
 ret = subprocess.call(args=sys.argv[1:], env=env)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
 return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Obviously it seems that the `subprocess` function is not able to find some of the files. So I tried to see what python is trying to call. The two parameters of `subrpocess` are:

```
['../../xgboost', './mushroom.aws.conf', 'nthread=1', 'data=s3://awstest.xgboost/xgb-demo/train', 'eval[test]=s3://awstest.xgboost/xgb-demo/test', 'model_dir=s3://awstest.xgboost/xgb-demo/model']
```

And the environment dictionary. The environment dictionary calls the `${PYTHONPATH}` variable, but it seems to be empty or at least when i echo it from terminal it is empty.

Do you have any clue of what is going wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major issue I see in your code is that you're using relative paths. The `dmlc-submit` command does not set the current directory in every node that it will use.
This is causing the python subprocess to tell you that it cannot find `../.../xgboost` binary as the paths are not the same.

I use absolute paths to overcome this problem.

Comment: Ok, now I am using relative paths, but now dmlc stops in `s3_filesys.cc`. The error is the following
`what():  [19:15:47] src/io/s3_filesys.cc:779: Check failed: curl_easy_perform(curl) == CURLE_OK 
Aborted (core dumped)`

Do I need to put some output string in the C code to understand what it is trying to call? What could be causing the problem? I also checked the permission of the s3 bucket and files and they should be ok

Comment: Probably I found the issue. It seems that the SSL certificate for contacting s3 is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the question was caused by a failed build of xgboost.

After that I started to have the following error

`what(): [19:15:47] src/io/s3_filesys.cc:779: Check failed: curl_easy_perform(curl) == CURLE_OK Aborted (core dumped)`

This last error comes from the fact that the S3 bucket didn't have a valid SSL certificate, so I modified the `s3_filesys.cc` source, replacing all the `https` with `http`